iOS 17.4 + version bug when copying and pasting HTML (rich) text
we have created a function that is expanding copy module to support html format. Everything inside that function works fine but on 17.4+ iOS versions copying the html element strike-through  <s>or <strike> tag is not working (other HTML elements are working fine). Looking the logs seems like <s> are getting stripped. Also list that have indents won't work on paste indent is missing.
Does anyone know fix for this or when this will be fixed or will it be fixed in next update?
void copyToClipboard(NSString *htmlContent) {     
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pasteboard setValue:htmlContent forPasteboardType:@"public.html"]; 
}


Why add the Swift and SwiftUI tags when your code example is purely Obj-C? If you're actually using Swift and SwiftUI as well and you know that's causing the issue, you should also include the relevant parts in the question. Either way, you need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.
